# indexeddb , how to use a cursor to update an array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

Question: How do I store a large array full of objects, all of which have 5 properties and all except the id property must be updated. Further more, why won't the code below work and how can I format it to work with the main question?

Info I've viewed:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/openCursor

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/createIndex

Note: I am aware of the `setInterval` and its inefficiency, it is for testing purposes so I do not have to click many times to check for a result.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let count =0;
    let storeBuilt = false;
    const dbName = "the_name";
    let version=82;
    let storeName= "store82";
    let storeBuilding= false;
    setInterval(build,1000/24);
    function build(){
        hello()
    }

    function hello(){

        let customerData = [];

        for(let i=0;i<=50000;i++){
            customerData.push({name:"bob",minX:random(),minY:random(),maxX:random(),maxY:random(),id:random()})
        }



        let request = indexedDB.open(dbName, version);

        request.onsuccess= function(event){
            let db = event.target.result;
            let transaction = db.transaction( storeName,"readwrite").objectStore(storeName);




            if( storeBuilding=== false&& storeBuilt=== false){
                storeBuilding= true;
                let additem = addData(customerData, transaction);
                additem.onsuccess= function(e){storeBuilt=true}
            } else if (storeBuilt=== true){

                let updateitem= updateData(customerData, transaction);
            }



        };





        request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
            let db = event.target.result;

            // Create an objectStore to hold information about our customers. We're
            // going to use "ssn" as our key path because it's guaranteed to be
            // unique - or at least that's what I was told during the kickoff meeting.
            let objectStore = db.createObjectStore(storeName, {keyPath:"names",autoIncrement:true});
            objectStore.createIndex("name","name",{unique:true});

            // Use transaction oncomplete to make sure the objectStore creation is
            // finished before adding data into it.
            objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
                // Store values in the newly created objectStore.
                let customerObjectStore = db.transaction(storeName, "readwrite").objectStore(storeName);





            }
        };}










    function random (){
        return (Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1))
    }
    function addData(data,transaction){
        return transaction.add(data)
    }

    function updateData(data,transaction){

        let openCursor = transaction.index("name").openCursor();

        openCursor.onsuccess= function(event){
            let cursor = event.target.result;

            if (cursor){
                alert (cursor);
                for(let I in data){
                    let item = data[I];
                    if(item.id === cursor.value.id){
                        let updateProperty = cursor.value;
                        updateProperty.minX = item.minX;
                        cursor.update(updateProperty);
                        cursor.continue()
                    }
                }
            }{alert("none")}
        }
    }

    function deleteData(data,transaction){


    }



</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the problem clearly, but generally you will want to load the objects from the object store, modify each object's properties, and then store the objects in the object store. There are several ways to do this. One way is to use cursor.update, but I don't think you need to do this at all. Just overwrite the objects.

```
function storeThings(db, things, callback) {
  var txn = db.transaction('store82', 'readwrite');
  txn.oncomplete = callback;
  var store = txn.objectStore('store82');
  for(var thing of things) {
    store.put(thing);
  } 
}

function open(callback) {
  var request = indexedDB.open();
  request.onsuccess = _ => callback(request.result);
}

var things = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
open(db => storeThings(db, things, _ => console.log('done')));
```

I am using IDBObjectStore.prototype.put to store the objects. The put method will either create or overwrite an object in the store. It will create a new object in the store when no matching object is found based on the keypath. It will replace an existing object in the store when a matching object is found.

In your case, you are using ssn string as a keypath. So, in other words, it will create new people if ssn not found, or overwrite people if ssn found. You just need to make sure that the ssn property is defined within each person object you pass to put, or indexedDB will complain.

Comment: The idea is to use a cursor and its update method instead so instead of replacing the entire objects it just changes the value . otherwise it can cause a memory leak when used with setinterval  that will crash in a matter of seconds. if this can be fixed id use it but the idea of the post is to use the cursor and its update method . sorry for the confusion , I do not mean to trouble people with this , I just thought that the cursor has not been properly explained to my liking otherwise id not be posting this in the first place. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I do not understand why you want to use cursor.update and I do not understand why you refer to setInterval

Comment: I have an array of objects and every object has five properties every 24th of a second (hense set interval) I want to update these objects by using a cursor and the update method on each individual object . I tried using the put method but for some reason it causes a memory leak that probably has something to do with structured cloning taking longer than the frame causing duplicates.

Comment: You want to update data in a database 4 times per second? My instinct is that this is not the purpose of indexedDB.

Comment: I know this and stated above regardless that is not what I am asking for , what I'm asking for could be done with or without setinterval. And if I could do it any other way I would.

Comment: cursor.update is just syntactic sugar for store.put. cursor.update is just a convenience method.

Comment: Ah kk, I had a feeling that was the case but some part of me just hoped this was a way of modifying it without deleting the original .

Comment: Thanks for the answer even know it's not the one I wanted to hear XD